# Android: Cursor out of bounds

Tags: java, android, database, cursor

I get a cursor out of bounds exception after clicking on my list adapter in Android for that displays data from my database.

This is my code that executes when I click my button:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle contactsState) {
    super.onCreate(contactsState);

 // Set the layout for this activity
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts);
    final Intent openInfo = new Intent(this,contactInfo.class);


    final database info = new database(this);
    info.open();
    getData = info.getData();
    getData.moveToFirst();
    ListAdapter Cview = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                        R.layout.row,
                        getData,
                        new String[]{info.KEY_CONTACT, info.KEY_PHONE},
                        new int[]{R.id.RowText});
    setListAdapter(Cview);

    ListView Vct;
    Vct = getListView();
    Vct.setClickable(true);
    Vct.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,View v,int position,long id){
            Click = (Cursor) a.getItemAtPosition(position);
            getId = Click.getLong(1);
            info.open();
            String Pdata = info.getRows(getId);
            openInfo.putExtra("data",Pdata);
            info.close();
            //Start the Activity
            startActivity(openInfo);


        }
    });

    info.close();

}
```

This is the part of my database that manages some of this code:

```
    public Cursor getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_CONTACT, KEY_PHONE, KEY_DAYS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    return c;
}
public String getRows(long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_CONTACT,KEY_PHONE,KEY_DAYS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null);
    String value = c.getString(1) + "\n" + c.getString(2) + "\n" + c.getString(3); 
    return value;
}
```

This is the Error I am getting:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1000856/

What this is supposed to do is when you click a name in the list view were that has data from the database in it, it will open a new activity that has a variable passed to it, and that variable will show info in the activity of the name.

```
    Thanks in Advance
```

Comment: Could you post the full exception stack trace for your error please - it might help us to better identify the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the row id of the cursor related to the position in the list you clicked, it's the `long id` parameter coming into the method.

You can skip the whole cursor issue you are running into like so (and get rid of come unnecessary code):

```
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,View v,int position,long id){
        info.open();
        String Pdata = info.getRows(id);
        openInfo.putExtra("data",Pdata);
        info.close();
        //Start the Activity
        startActivity(openInfo);
    }
```

**EDIT**

With your further information... the problem is in your getRows method... you need to do `moveToFirst()` before you do anything with a cursor.

Try this:

```
public String getRows(long id) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_CONTACT,KEY_PHONE,KEY_DAYS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();  // <---- add this
    String value = c.getString(1) + "\n" + c.getString(2) + "\n" + c.getString(3); 
    return value;
}
```

And my first answer should work with this as well.

**EDIT 2**

It also looks like you are missing an intent declaration... you are using putExtra but I don't see the call to create the `openInfo` intent.

Comment: I just updated the post, I left out some important information, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I never noticed that I left that out and probably would have never known that it was needed. Thanks again.